# Python: hangman program

Tags: python, string

I am posting my question on stack overflow because I didn't know what to search and when I did the answers seemed completely irrevelant.

Anyways, this is my code:

```
from random import randrange
# - System Variables -
gm = 1
pv = ""
words = ["city", "cube", "keyhole", 'puppy', 'program', 'clock', 'glass', 'material', 'bottle', 'wall', 'shoes', 'lights', 'sound', 'image', 'hearing', 'machine', 'mouse', 'puppet', 'wagon', 'reward', 'table', 'ceiling', 'plank', 'electric', 'country', 'music', 'branch', 'flute', 'wind', 'tile']
# - Game -
While gm == 0:
    wn = randrange(31) - 1
    word = words[wn]
    while pv == word:
        pv = word
        wn = randrange(31) - 1
        word = words[wn]
```

I'm trying to make a python hangman game, and I made the loop and such.

*My questions*

I. I need to make a string that is (insert length of the picked string) underscores, and there will be a loop using the string "letter" that tells what letter the user picked. How do I make it so the string displays underscores where it is not guessed and the letter guessed when it is?

II. I need to make every letter that the player enters caps automatically. How would I do this?

III. How do I detect if the letter the user entered is in the word?

Thanks!

Comment: a quick note of clarity -- rather than gm == 0 while your game is running, make gm a boolean, name it something explicit (`game_running = True`) etc, and do `while game_running:` Always try to have your variable names be self-descriptive unless it's a commonly used abbreviation (`i` for index, `cls` for class, `k,v` for key,value, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I. I need to make a string that is (insert length of the picked string) underscores, and there will be a loop using the string "letter" that tells what letter the user picked. How do I make it so the string displays underscores where it is not guessed and the letter guessed when it is?*

Consider a comprehension-type approach like

```
>>> guesses = ['H','A']
>>> secret = 'HANGMAN'
>>> state = ''.join(x if x in guesses else '_' for x in secret)
>>> state
'HA___A_'
```

It may serve you well to include some spaces in there as well, to make it clear how many letters are in there.  (Note the space in the string before `join`):

```
>>> state = ' '.join(x if x in guesses else '_' for x in secret)
>>> state
'H A _ _ _ A _'
```

---

> *II. I need to make every letter that the player enters caps automatically. How would I do this?*

Something like `upper()` should work

```
>>> guess = 'a'
>>> guess.upper()
'A'
```

---

> *III. How do I detect if the letter the user entered is in the word?*

The comprehension-type approach I used above will do that.  If you want to do it explicitly, you could use something like:

```
if letter in secret:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `''.join(c if c in found else '_' for c in word)` - that uses `_` unless the char is already in `found` (where you'd store any char the user entered as a guess)
2. Any string in python has an [`upper()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) method, e.g. `somechar.upper()`
3. Strings are [sequences](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) and thus can be used with the `in` operator like this: `foo in bar`